# UTF-8 Characters in Byobu Screen Status Line

Tags: gnu-screen, unicode, byobu

I'm running Byobu with Screen backend. I have a custom status script that wget's an RSS feed and shows the latest headline in it.  If there are non-ASCII characters, they are not printed correctly.  I've tried everything I could find Googling for properly enabling UTF-8 in Screen - all to no avail.  I put together the sample script below that will demonstrate the problem.  Does anyone know what I need to do to get Byobu/Screen displaying this correctly in the status line?

```
#!/bin/bash
SAMPLE=$(wget -q -O- "http://cnnespanol.cnn.com" | grep '<title>' | sed 's|.*<title>\(.*\)</title>|\1|' | head -n 1)
COLOR="= kr"
printf "\005{-}\005{$COLOR}$SAMPLE\005{-}\005{bw}"
echo
```

That script displays this text:

```
CNN en EspaÃ±ol: Ultimas Noticias de Estados Unidos, LatinoamÃ©rica y el Mundo, OpiniÃ³n y
```

Versions I am running:

- Linux: Mint 14.1 w/ Cinnamon
- byobu version 5.21
- Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is unable to cleanly support UTF8 in the status bar.  This was one of [several reasons](http://blog.dustinkirkland.com/2011/12/byobu-5-released.html) why I added the Tmux backend support to [Byobu](http://byobu.co).

*Full disclosure: I'm the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*